# facing error while capturing value from mail to loadrunner script

Tags: performance, loadrunner

i have a loadrunner script where i need to capture value from mail and need to pass that value in my script as peramater in middle of execution.

i tried to capture that using Correlation but that dosen't happen.

Comment: Email is generally a different protocol than is your core application.   This is especially true for web versus traditional email client protocols.

Comment: If this question is still relevant, please share your code